# how to split calculation job evenly between clients

Tags: c#, permutation, combinatorics

i got a bit of a problem.

I've got an input: "/0-9/0-9/0-9/0-9". in this case its 10^4 possibilities.

my program analyze it and calculate all the permutations, and prints the output. in our case the output is: 
0001
0002
 .
 .
 .
9999

the problem is that i have a server application (written in c#) that receives this input, and suppose to split the task of the calculation evenly between the connected clients. in the end each client need to print his part.

the limitation is that the format of the task sent by the server to the client must be in the format "/#-#/#-#/#-#/#-#/" 
server can send more then one task to each client providing all the clients get same number of tasks.

one more example:
i got two connected clients. and my input is /0-9/0-9/0-9/0-9/
so i'll send:

clinet1: /0-4/0-9/0-9/0-9/

clinet2: /5-9/0-9/0-9/0-9/

how do i split evenly between n clients?

tnx

Comment: Surely you send alternating items to various clients? so, if you had 2 clients, client a gets 1,3,5,7 client b gets 2,4,6,8.. if you had 3 clients its 1,4,7,10, 2,5,8,11 and 3,6,9,12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by figuring out how many of the `10^4` possibilities each client needs to solve if you were to distribute the items evenly:

```
Items per client = 10^4 / N
```

Say `N = 20`, then `Items per client = 500`. So now you need to break up the input into groups of 500

```
0-0/0-4/0-9/0-9  (0 - 499)
0-0/5-9/0-9/0-9  (500 - 999)
1-1/0-4/0-9/0-9  (1000 - 1499)
1-1/5-9/0-9/0-9  (1500 - 1999)
2-2/0-4/0-9/0-9  (2000 - 2499)
etc etc
```

This becomes a little messier when N does not divide evenly into 10^4 but you can simply round the # of jobs to send to each client up so that clients occasionally overlap on jobs at the endpoints of the intervals

Edit: Example if N = 3 then Items per client = 3333.333. Then round this down to 3000 each and have the last one do 4000

```
Client 1: 0-2/0-9/0-9/0-9
Client 2: 3-5/0-9/0-9/0-9
Client 3: 6-9/0-9/0-9/0-9
```

You could generalize this algorithm to split up the items evenly. If N is between 1-10 then you will be splitting the first interval. If N is between 11-100 then you will be splitting the 2nd interval. If N is between 101 - 1000 you will be splitting on the 3rd interval

Comment: thank you for you answer, but that don't help me. you gave example for the most simple case, witch is easy to handle. what about it i got 3 clients.

Comment: @urban48 edited to show 3 clients. The same technique still works... You can get around figuring out how to split up the later groups if you round the values down and allow 1 client to do slightly more to make up the difference. Alternatively you could round the work up for all clients so they all do extra work and discard some of the excess results